# Don't have keyboard section in system settings anymore

Tags: settings, keyboard

the other day, my keyboard and mouse stopped working after an update at restart
So I ran this command `sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-input-all`
And now, I wanted to add a keyboard shortcut and realised that I don't have the keyboard section in my system settings anymore.

I don't know what I should do so I'm asking for your help =)

Thanks for reading.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Found a solution.
I went to the AppCenter and I could download the Keyboard extension system Settings [image]